# Users and roles: Where to put queryUsersWithRole()?

Tags: design, query, dao

I have two model classes `User` and `Role` and two managers/DAOs (`UserManager` and `RoleManager`) plus a method which gives me all users with a certain role (`List<User> getUsersWithRole(Role)`).

In which manager does this method belong and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are expecting a list of Users from the `getUsersWithRole(Role)` method **it belongs in the UserManager**.

You a making a query for Users (which are handled by UserManager), just with a filter on their Role.

Comment: I tend to agree but that eventually turns `UserManager` into a god class of sorts because almost every object in my model has a relation to `User`.

Comment: I don't see your point. All those objects having a relation with `User` don't need to know about `UserManager`, or vice versa. Only those that spawn new instances (via the manager) need to know about the manager, and the manager should be there only to spawn, safe or remove Users. 
If you have a method for every query you might end up with a big class, but in my opinion that would be appropriate.